# How to type œ and ç in LaTex and Markdown?

Tags: overleaf, markdown, french

I used to solve the problem of typing Dutch letters by `$\acute{e}$`, `$\ddot{e}$` and so on. And I get by. But now that I need to type some French, I can't get away with œ and ç. What's the most handy way to type those French letters in LaTex and Markdown? Say, I'm using Overleaf and Joplin?

--------------------------------=

BTW, more than one comments mentioned typing the characters directly. I'm curious. How? Does it require some special type of keyboard?

Comment: Simply, use œ and ç. If you are able to write these characters to the title of this question, then you are able to write them to the TeX or Markdown source. And use Unicode fonts.

Comment: Never, ever, write `$\acute{e}$` or `$\ddot{e}$` -- *unless* you want to denote the accented math variable `é` or the second derivative of the variable `e` with respective to time `t` (*and* prefer to use Newtonian to Leibnizian notation for derivatives). For the text-mode accented characters, do please write `\'e` and `\"e`, respectively.

Comment: @wipet Looks like an answer to me

Comment: @Mico Yes, I agree. Thank you very much!

Comment: œ and ç.  work even if not using Unicode fonts.

Answer (score 4):

I use this

```
ç
```

This is simple and useful method. And œ can be input using `œ`.

If my keyboard doesn't support `ç`, then I can define

```
\def\cc{ç}
```

and then use `\cc` instead `ç`. The body of the definition can be created by copying from a web page, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
\c{c}
```

This is a simple and useful method.

Comment: And œ can be input using `\oe`.

Comment: Yes, i have tried this method.

Answer (score 0):

I find it very handy to use [html entities](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) in Joplin (Markdown)

```markdown
Le fran$&ccedil;$ais est impossible $&agrave;$ prononcer.
```

Comment: In a scale of "unreadable source" this pretty much wins. Why would you use this over the answer you acknowledge in the comments, i.e., just type the characters directly?

Comment: @AlanMunn because I can't type those characters directly lol

Comment: So how did you manage to type them in the title of the question? Every OS has a way to type such characters.

Comment: Windows: https://blog.pcrisk.com/windows/13360-how-to-type-characters-with-accents-in-windows-10 Mac: https://appleinsider.com/articles/18/03/16/how-to-type-accented-letters-in-macos-three-different-ways Linux: https://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Accented_Characters

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you! I had to copy from webpage... lol

Comment: Please don't wrap non-math letters in `$` signs in text.  At best, the resulting letters will be set in italic; more likely the result will be error messages.